# karate scenario outline - Create a dynamic example table based on JSON array index size

Tags: karate

Here I would like to clarify about creating dynamic example table for a dynamic JSON index size

My JSON looks like

**Env - Dev - 2 servers**

```
"response": {
    "abc": [{
            "status": "pass"
                .
                .
        },
        {
            "status": "pass"
                .
                .
        }
    ]
}
```

**Env - Uat - 3 servers**

```
{
    "response": {
        "abc": [{
                "status": "pass"
            },
            {
                "status": "pass"
            },
            {
                "status": "pass"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**My scenario outline looks like**

```
Scenario Outline: validating .....

When def result = callonce read('featurefilename@tagname')

Then print result

And print <status>

And print ...

And match ....

Examples:

|result.response.abc|
```

**Errors for the above:**

1) * dynamic expression evaluation failed:result.response.abc

2) com.intuit.karate.karateExpresion: ---- javascript evaluation failed result.response.abc, ReferenceError:"result" is not defined in  at line number 1

Note - If I move step 'When def result = callonce read('featurefilename@tagname') to background it's working as expected but I can't use background in my feature file due to other factors.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of providing index in a table you can leverage [Dynamic Scenario Outline](https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline) feature in karate.

In this case you you can pass the variable as a input to `Examples`. If the JSON provided above is from variable `result` then,

```
Examples:
 | result.response.abc |
```

Refer the docs for more insights.

Comment: Thanks for your information, it's getting failed error message - "* dynamic expression evaluation failed: response.abc".  1) not executed even 1 step. - reference error is - "response" is not a <eval> at line 1 2) let me give you my scenario as well. When def result = call once read(featurename@tagname)   Then print ...  And print ...

Comment: Sry your scenario is not clear. Please update your question with scenario, also refer my updated answer

Comment: Updated my question and explained in detail, Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: @chandrashekar please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue